# Factor $x^7 + x + 1$ over $\mathbb{F}_7$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, factoring

This is a problem from Artin's *Algebra*.

According to Mathematica the factorization is

$$x^7 + x + 1 = (x + 4)(x^2 + x + 3)(x^2 + x + 4)(x^2 + x + 6)$$

Is there some clever trick to avoid doing this by trial and error? It's not that hard to see that 3 is a root, but I don't see how to find the quadratic factors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider what elements $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{7^k}$ could possibly be a root, other than $3$. Since $x \mapsto x^7$ is the Frobenius map, if $\alpha$ has minimal polynomial $f(x)$ then $\alpha^7$ must also be a root of $f(x)$. But we have $\alpha^7 = - \alpha - 1$ by assumption, so $f(x)$ must be divisible by

$$(x - \alpha)(x + \alpha + 1) = x^2 + x - (\alpha^2 + \alpha).$$

Conversely, any irreducible polynomial of the form $x^2 + x + a \in \mathbb{F}_7[x]$ must be a factor, because it must have a root with the above property. This reduces the problem to figuring out when $x^2 + x + a$ is irreducible. The discriminant here is $\sqrt{1 - 4a}$ which lies in $\mathbb{F}_7$ iff $1 - 4a = 0, 1, 2, 4$, hence iff $a = 2, 0, 5, 1$. So $x^2 + x + a$ is irreducible iff $a = 3, 4, 6$, which must be precisely the three irreducible quadratic factors.

Comment: One also needs to consider the possibility that $\alpha = - \alpha - 1$, which happens iff $\alpha = 3$, but that linear term was already dealt with.

Answer (score 4):

Let $u = x+4$. Then the polynomial becomes 
$$
u^7+u=u(u^2+1)(u^2+2)(u^2+4) \, .
$$

Comment: Very nice! And the same argument as in my answer applies; the roots of this polynomial are $\alpha$ satisfying $\alpha^7 = - \alpha$, so either they are in $\mathbb{F}_7$ or their minimal polynomials are divisible by $(x - \alpha)(x + \alpha) = x^2 - \alpha^2$.

Comment: I am pretty sure that's how Artin came up with the problem. And it is very instructive as your analysis shows.